# Get the next div in the doc after the current one with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click of the current div i want the very next div with the same class name in the entire document. Document is having a very complex nested structure.

```
<div><div><div class='1'></div></div></div>
<div><div class='1'></div></div>
<div><div><div><div><div class='1'></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Would the next `div` be on the same level, a child, a parent or any one of those?
Could you give an example of the structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the elements are **not** siblings, you could do something like this:

```
var $elements = $('.someClass');

$elements.click(function() {
    var $nextElement = $elements.eq($elements.index(this) + 1);
});
```

**Reference:** [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/S7W8P/)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('currentDiv .className').click(function(){
    var target = jQuery(this).next('.className');
});
```

Comment: Same here: This will give you the next sibling only if it matches the selector. It does not give you the next sibling that matches the selector.